# Flutter Google Maps plugin - Cannot find drag events?

Tags: dart, flutter

I've been using the Flutter Google Maps plugin now. The only event I can find using this plugin is the: onMapCreated plugin.

Is there any alternative for the lack of these events (I understand the plugin is still in its infancy)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: the plugin is in alpha. I wouldn't expect much.
I would look at this example. It was committed a few week later after your question
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/scrolling_map.dart

Comment: A similar question has some answers may be that can help
follow the link below https://stackoverflow.com/a/55141165/9307934 this has few solutions

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use onCameraMove callback.
Like
`onCameraMove: (CameraPosition position){ print("I M Dragging"); },`